# I'm facing an issue when I'm adding java to sql

Tags: java, sql

Well, I want to update an SQL query with a chunk of java code but it doesn't work. I don't know if I'm using the right way to do it.

Here my code :

```
String GICA_petrom_filter = "";

if (context.yoda_core_country.equals("ROU")) {
  GICA_petrom_filter = "AND NASSAS NOT IN (SELECT MAG FROM'" + context.link_GICA_PETROM_Schema + "'.PETROM)";
}
```

Can I use a prepared statement ? not sure if it's efficient...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should not concatenate strings like this in SQL, it is a really bad habit, this should help you https://www.baeldung.com/sql-injection

Try to use query builders, or the methods described if the article linked above

And then you're missing a space after the

> AND NASSAS NOT IN (SELECT MAG FROM'"

change it to :

> AND NASSAS NOT IN (SELECT MAG FROM '"

But as I said, you should not concatenate to build queries like this ;)
Also try posting the errors you get in the log, when you ask a question, it helps a lot to solve your issues !

Comment: Thanks your help, also for sql injection I'm using talend so I'm not going to face this kind of issue.

Comment: Good to know ! did this solve your issue ? or is it still not working ? If it did you can mark this as "answered" if there are no better answers